# Can't open SQLCompact database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce, database-connection

I am working with a SQL compact database and I am able to test the connection when I import it and copy the exact file path to my code, but it still says that it hasn't been opened.  What am I doing wrong?  Are there any shortcuts available if I have already added the database to my project?

Thanks!

```
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe 

Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim constring As String = "Data Source=C:\Users\test\Desktop\MyDatabase1.sdf"

    Dim conn As New SqlCeConnection(constring)

    Dim cmd As New SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT")

    conn.Open()

    Dim reader As SqlCeDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While reader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine(reader)
    End While


End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the connection to the command:

Immediately after this line:

```
conn.Open()
```

add:

```
cmd.Connection = conn
```

Alternatively, you can add the connection to the command's constructor:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT", conn)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  If it isn't a problem could you take a look at my loop.  I am trying to print each row to the console, but I just get a reference to the object.  I come from python and queries come back as list that you can iterate over.  Does vb.net have any features that allow you to do that?

Comment: @LanceCollins: When you loop through the reader like you are, the reader object inside the loop will be pointed at the current row. In order to retrieve data from that row, you can use several different approaches: `reader(0)` to retrieve the first column, `reader("columnName")` to retrieve the specified column (both of these are shortcuts to the default `Item` property) or any of the relevant `Get` methods (i.e. `GetInt32`, `GetString`, etc. However, the `Get` methods need an ordinal for the column index, which you can first retrieve using `GetOrdinal`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main advantage of using SQL server CE (3.5) is to have Linq to SQL. You should make use of  strongly typed database, and of DataContext. if you do so, then creating a new DataContext is ONE line of code, not 8. And if your DataBase file does not exist, the CreateDataTable method of your DataContext will create them for you. Dig a little into this, because using SQL Server CE like an old fashion OLEDB data provider is... well... not optimal :-)

Comment: Great point.  I'm new to .Net so I will be buying a book on LINQ.

Comment: well why not, but you allready have some input in msdn, tutorials on the net, ...stackoverflow..., and others. Just a small overview of Linq To Sql here : http://dotnetjquerymvcbugkiller.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/linq-beats-sql/

Comment: Vincent - I did some research on SQLCompact 3.5 and I don't think I will be able to utilize LINQ to SQL with it because I am using VB 2010 express.  Thanks for the info though, looks like I'll have to shell out the $ for the professional version.

Comment: :-( Sometimes you can get extra features for free if you get the right SDK that includes it... Donno for this one, though.

Comment: True.  I don't have a problem paying for good tools, but $599 is a steep price to pay for an amature dev...